# vue-typeahead says you need to provide a HTTP client

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, axios

When I try to load vue-typeahead in my browser it says 'you need to provide a http client.'  How exactly do I do this?

I am using webpack (the default configuration that comes with laravel 5.5).  I have copied the usage example verbatim from here, https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-typeahead, and placed it in its own file, `typeahead.vue`.

I have then added the file as a vue component as follows:

```
Vue.component('typeahead', require('./components/admin/shared/typeahead.vue'));
```

The webpack bundling works fine (`npm run dev`), and I can see that the component loads in my browser, but when I type a few characters and trigger the http request, I get the error message.

Axios is loaded as part of bootstrapping my Vue instance, but presumably it needs to be passed to the vue-typeahead somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs are not very clear.

But look in the samples directory: You have to set the $http property on the Vue prototype.

You have to use a http client that provides an interface compatible with the axios package

https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-typeahead/blob/master/demo/main.js

Looks like the source only uses `get(url, params)`, so if you want to roll your own http client instead of using axios it’s not a ton of work.